# How to set Persistent-Auth:true in IIS and what is the use of it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am in learning phase of WEB API and i just want to know how to set Persistent-Auth as true for my service response and what is the benefit by doing this?

Answer (score 2):

For IIS 7.x the setting is: authPersistSingleRequest. Setting this flag to True specifies that authentication persists only for a single request on a connection. IIS resets the authentication at the end of each request, and forces re-authentication on the next request of the session. The default value is False.

For more information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication/