# How to remove Persistent-Auth header from ASP.NET CORE 3.1 HTTP responses?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-security

I need to remove this header from all the http reponses in a ASP.NET CORE web app :
[image]

I tried adding it in the web.config file: `<remove name="Persistent-Auth" />`, using a middleware to delete it from the http responses and also using the configurationBuilder from Program.cs, nothing worked. What can I do ?

Comment: First, why do you want this? This is used for Windows Authentication which depends on the actual server you use (Kester? IIS?). We can't help without knowing which server you use or how you configured Windows Auth. Second, ASP.NET Core 3.1 reached End-of-Life. The oldest supported .NET Core version is .NET 6

Comment: As [the header docs explain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-n2ht/84d276f8-3632-44e8-a2ff-b169c693049d) this is just a hint to the client that authentication may not be needed on every single call. The *server* can still require reauthentication. You'd have to configure your server (whichever it is) to actually require auth on every request though.

Comment: As [this related SO question shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32018752/how-to-set-persistent-authtrue-in-iis-and-what-is-the-use-of-it) in IIS you need to set [authPersistSingleRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/settings-schema/aa347472(v=vs.90)).

Comment: It has been requested by my security team to remove this header. I'm using IIS Server with windows authentication. I know it's an old technology but we do not plan to upgrade it right now.

Comment: @Daniel Does your "security team" have a _well-reasoned_ (ideally evidence-based) policy regarding the `Persistent-Auth` header, or is this something they're uncritically repeating off an online vuln scanner report?

Comment: Ok, so after I discussed again with them, they decided it's not a vulnerability so I don't need to remove it anymore. Thank you for the provided help.